# I know that $G$ is finitely generated free group with generating set $S$, $G=\langle S\rangle $. Is $G$, free with base $S$?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a group.

Then, $G$ is free iff there exists $X\subset G$ such that for any group $H$ and a function $f\in H^X$, there exists a unique $\phi\in Hom(G,H)$ such that $\phi\upharpoonright X=f$. It can be shown that if $G$ is a group and $X\subseteq G$, then $G$ is free with base $X$ if and only if every $g\in G$ can be uniquely written in the form $g=x_1 x_2\ldots x_n$ where $0\leq n$, $x_i\in X\cup X^{-1}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ and $x_{i+1}\neq x_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$.

Question. I know that $G$ is finitely generated free group with generating set $S$, $G=\langle S\rangle$. Is $G$, free with base $S$? ($S$ is symetric)

Comment: What do you think? Did you try to study the case $|X|=1$ and $|S|=2$?

Comment: @Moishe Cohen. Thanks. If $G$ is a finitely generated group. Can I find a generating set $S$ such that $S$ is symmetric and $G=<S>$ is free with base $S$?

Comment: Try the same setting as I suggested in the 1st comment.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Obviously a free group is not free on every possible generating set - the generating set could consist of the whole group for example. But what do you mean by symmetric? If you mean closed under inversion then the answer is no. A free base of a group is not closed under inversion. For example a free base of an infinite cyclic group has a single generator $a$, not two generators $a$ and $a^{-1}$.

Comment: A generating set doesn't have to be a basis.